# Best way to distribute code to airflow webserver / scheduler + workers and workflow

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

What do people find is the best way to distribute code (dags) to airflow webserver / scheduler + workers?  I am trying to run celery on a large cluster of workers such that any manual updates are impractical.

I am deploying airflow on docker and using s3fs right now and it is crashing on me constantly and creating weird core.### files. I am exploring other solutions (ie StorageMadeEasy, DropBox, EFS, a cron job to update from git...) but would love a little feedback as I explore solutions.

Also how do people typically make updates to dags and distribute that code?  If one uses a share volume like s3fs, every time you update a dag do you restart the scheduler?  Is editing the code in place on something like DropBox asking for trouble?  Any best practices on how update dags and distribute the code would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't really tell you what the "best" way of doing it is but I can tell you what I've done when I needed to distribute the workload onto another machine.

I simply set up an NFS share on the airflow master for the both the DAGS and the PLUGINS folders and mounted this share onto the worker. I had an issue once or twice where the NFS mount point would break for some reason but after re-mounting the jobs continued.

To distribute the DAG and PLUGIN code to the Airflow cluster I just deploy it to the master (I do this by bash script on my local machine which just SCPs the folders up from my local git branch) and NFS handles the replication to the worker. I always restart everything after a deploy, I also don't deploy while a job is running.

A better way to deploy would be to have GIT on the airflow master server which checks out a branch from a GIT repository (test or master depending on the airflow server?) and then replace the dags and plugins with the ones in the git repository. I'm experimenting with doing deployments like this at the moment with Ansible.